# Block slicing with step in python

Tags: python, list, slice

I am wondering if it is possible to subindex every n'th block in python. It is possible to do

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
a[::2]
```

which gives every second value

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

but what if I want something like:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

so basically every 2nd block with length 2. Is this possible with subindexing somehow?

Comment: Anything is possible. Where is your attempt at solving this?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But I am wondering if it is possible with subindexing?

Answer (score 0):

you can work around like this

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = list(itertools.chain(*[a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)][::2]))
assert b == [1,2,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

You could do the following but you lose the ordering of the array

```
a[::4] + a[1::4]
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 2, 6]
```

With numpy you can create a mask with modulo like this:

```
import numpy as np
mod4 = np.arange(len(a)) % 4
np.array(a)[(mod4==0) | (mod4==1)]
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 5, 6])
```